# Bootstrap: Can't align inputs on the same row

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am still new to bootstrap and also html/css at that.
What I am trying to do is to align the inputs on the same row,
I've looked up advice and have put it in a container but the
two inputs are still showing on different rows.

html

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-md">
                    <h3>Startdate From:</h3>
                    <input name="stardatefromDTP" type="date" />
                 </div> 
                <div class="col-md">
                    <h3>Startdate To:</h3>
                    <input name="stardatetoDTP" type="date" />
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, though you'll need to mess around with the column sizes to get the formatting exactly how you would like:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h3>Startdate From:</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input name="stardatefromDTP" type="date" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h3>Startdate To:</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input name="stardatetoDTP" type="date" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use the label element instead:

```
<label class="h3" for="startdate">Startdate From:</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="startdate" />
```

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I believe `h3` is a block element so the col-md will stretch to accommodate. Try col-md-6 to force it to be smaller. The col classes refer to columns and bootstrap divides the screen into 12, so col-md-6 should make room for 2 inputs in 1 row.

Comment: thanks for sharing, I ended up using my label as a content. Also I noticed bootstrap wasn't loaded and had to do it manually with <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. in visual studio

Comment: Haha, been there!